# WordPress DO i need an exit() after redirecting a url

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I have a gateway plugin and I added the code below to `redirect` the customer to a custom page when the payment fails.

My question is, do I need to add `exit();` after the end of the `redirect_url` which is inside the if statement?

I have seen some codes `with exit` and `some without`.

```
else {
        //failed
        $this->msg['class'] = 'error';
        $this->msg['message'] = __( "Your Transaction Has Failed Due to Some Technical Error. Please Try Again.<br/><br/>", 'toBeTranslatd');
        $order->update_status('failed');
        $order->add_order_note('Failed');
        $order->add_order_note($this->msg['message']);
        $redirect_url = home_url( '/payment-faild/' );

        $lang_code = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'wpml_language', true );
        if ( $lang_code === ar ) {
            $redirect_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $redirect_url, $lang_code );
            //exit(); // Do I need this or delete it?
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress provides two functions for this:

> - [`wp_redirect`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/#description)

and

> - [`wp_safe_redirect`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/#description)

And here's what wordpress recommends:

> Note: `wp_redirect()` and `wp_safe_redirect()` do not exit automatically, and should **almost always** be followed by a call to **exit;**

Answer (score 0):

wp_redirect() or wp_safe_redirect() does not exit or die automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit or die();

Reference : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect

Thank you.